# Implementing a setTimeout() wrapper as a method in Element.prototype

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to add a method to Element.prototype that would call the user function with the same `this` as the current object, via the system setTimeout(). My implementation looks as follows:

```
Element.prototype.timeout =
    function (func, delay)
    {
        var that = this;
        return setTimeout(function () { func.call(that) }, delay);
    }
```

Is there a more efficient or elegant way of doing this?

(no jQuery please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid lambda function, you can do something like:

```
Function.prototype.delay = function (delay, context) {
  this.self = context;
  this.args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return setTimeout(this, delay);
};

(function () {
  var self = arguments.callee.self || this;
  var args = arguments.callee.args || Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  alert(args[0]);
}).delay(1500, null, 42);
```

But it's quite ugly to do that.

Comment: @mojuba
I recently discover `Function.prototype.bind` method, which provide partial apply (Javascript 1.8.5 but with workaround)

let see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout

So, you can write:

`setTimeout((function (value) { alert(value); }).bind(null, 42), 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I can think of it to just make it a utility function like this that you could use with any function or method on any object:

```
function delayMethod(obj, method, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        method.call(obj);
    }, delay);
}
```

or, a bit more extensible with a variable number of arguments:

```
function delayMethod(obj, method, delay /* args to method go here */) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 3);
    setTimeout(function() {
        method.apply(obj, args);
    }, delay);
}
```

Comment: I see, but can it be more efficient? I doubt it.

Comment: There's no meaningful difference in efficiency.  What does "efficiency" mean with a delayed execution function?  What do you want to be more efficient?

Comment: For example, to eliminate the extra anonymous function. But no, looks like there is no way in this situation.

Comment: You cannot eliminate the extra function unless you want to just do a straight function call without setting `this` and without passing arguments because all `setTimeout()` knows how to do by itself is do a straight function call.